# Process launch exception "filename or extension is too long", can it be caused by arg line and not filename?

Tags: c#, process

I'm using System.Process to launch an external program, and I've just got a "filename or extension is too long" exception. However, I believe that filename is fine, but arguments is one hell of a long string (33,000 symbols). Can that string cause the exception?

Comment: show us your code, we can't guess what your are doing.

Comment: The limit, and error reporting, might be different between `UseShellExecute = true` and `UseShellExecute = false`.  I would try changing that property and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/10/56028.aspx

Comment: @VioletGiraffe sorry but you couldn't because the max length for a file in winfs(the file system of win7) is 2047 char. For ntfs it's 255

Comment: @Tinwor: Not everything passed on the command line is a filename, and the NTFS limit you mention is for each part of a path, not the overall path length (which can reach 3276x characters when properly escaped).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  That text is the error message corresponding to `ERROR_FILENAME_EXCED_RANGE`, and other users report that it applies to the overall command length and not just the executable filename.  See also

- [What processing/validation is performed on command line arguments before a process starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4629856/103167)

You are certainly exceeding the limit, although I agree the error message could be better.  The `CreateProcess` documentation says:

> `lpCommandLine [in, out, optional]`
>
> The command line to be executed. The maximum length of this string is 32,768 characters, including the Unicode terminating null character. If `lpApplicationName` is NULL, the module name portion of `lpCommandLine` is limited to `MAX_PATH` characters.

For `ShellExecute` the limit is even lower.  Hans linked a great blog series by Raymond Chen that discussed these limits and workarounds, see the question comments.